# opening camera and gallery from recycler view adapter using OnActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I created a part in my adapter that is responsible for editing profile picture , I am using a library called [android image cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) , which need on activity result to run , but since I am in adapter class, It does not let me use Activity methods. I searched but I could not understand the codes, because most of the use activity and I use fragment. this is my adapter class(only a part of it):

```
     holder.btn_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        final LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
                        View add_view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_addcontacts,null);
                        AlertDialog alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
                        alertDialog.setView(add_view);
                        final TextInputEditText edt_name=add_view.findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
                        final TextInputEditText edt_phonenumber=add_view.findViewById(R.id.edt_number);
                        byte[] contactimage=phonebookModel.getImage();
                        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(contactimage,0,contactimage.length);
                        final CircleImageView image_profile=add_view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
                        Button btn_add=add_view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
                        btn_add.setText("change");
                        edt_name.setText(phonebookModel.getName());
                        edt_phonenumber.setText(phonebookModel.getPhonenumber());
                        image_profile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        image_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
CropImage.activity()
                        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.OVAL)
                        .setMaxCropResultSize(2500,2500)
                        .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                        .setScaleType(CropImageView.ScaleType.CENTER)
                        .start(getContext(),ContactsFragment.this);

            }
                              
                            }
                        });
     private byte[] imagetobyte(CircleImageView image){
            Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50,stream);
            byte[] bytearray=stream.toByteArray();
            return bytearray;
    
        }
```

and this is my fragment:

```
public class ContactsFragment extends Fragment {

     RecyclerView recyclerView;
     FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
     PhoneBookDB phoneBookDB;
    CircleImageView imagebutton;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactsfragment,container,false);
        phoneBookDB =new PhoneBookDB(getContext());
        //recycler-contacts
        recyclerView= view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_contacts);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
        List<PhonebookModel> models=phoneBookDB.getalldata();
        Contactsadapter adapter=new Contactsadapter(models,getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //add-contacts
        floatingActionButton=view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_contacts);
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showdialog();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public void showdialog() {
            final LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            View add_view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_addcontacts,null);
            final AlertDialog alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
            alertDialog.setView(add_view);
            final TextInputEditText edt_name=add_view.findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
            final TextInputEditText edt_phonenumber=add_view.findViewById(R.id.edt_number);
            imagebutton=add_view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CropImage.activity()
                        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.OVAL)
                        .setMaxCropResultSize(2500,2500)
                        .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                        .setScaleType(CropImageView.ScaleType.CENTER)
                        .start(getContext(),ContactsFragment.this);

            }
        });
            Button btn_add=add_view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
            Button btn_cancel=add_view.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
            btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (!edt_name.getText().toString().isEmpty()&&!edt_phonenumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        long i=  phoneBookDB.insertdata(edt_name.getText().toString(), edt_phonenumber.getText().toString(),imagetobyte(imagebutton));
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), i+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class));
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "لطفا تمامی فیلد های خواسته شده را پر کنید", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                try {
                    InputStream inputStream= getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(resultUri);
                    imagebutton.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream));

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }
    }
    private byte[] imagetobyte(CircleImageView image){
            Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50,stream);
            byte[] bytearray=stream.toByteArray();
            return bytearray;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding so far by reading your question, I assume that you would like to start the library activity using `CropImage.activity()...` and get the crop result with `onActivityResult` inside Fragment.

In order to get the crop result with `onActivityResult` inside Fragment, I assume you need to start the library activity using `Fragment#startActivityForResult`.

To call `Fragment#startActivityForResult` when adapter item is clicked, I can think of two ways:

1. Pass the instance of fragment to the adapter class and start activity from fragment when the item is clicked.
2. Define and pass a on listener from fragment to adapter to make it possible to handle adapter's on click event

Maybe the issue and the comment below helps:
https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/762#issuecomment-648859151

---

(Maybe it would be helpful if you could clarify both what you know or do, what you have tried, and what you do not know about so it makes it easier for others to understand your situation and understanding level. For example, you could give us some other codes or logics that you have already tried to let others understand your situation clearer. )

Comment: using library in fragment is not what I want , using it in adapter class is